# Slider, disallow sliding past a value X, which is not min or max

Tags: react-native

I created a simplified Snack of this issue: https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/range-slider

For both Android and iOS. I have created a slider like this:

```
render() {
    return <Slider minimumValue={0} maximumValue={100} value={this.state.value} onSlidingComplete={this.setValue} />
}

setValue = value => this.setState(() => ({ value }))
```

Now sliders are not exactly controlled components. The user can freely slide, and then after they release, then the value is set. We can try to control it with `onValueChange`, it will control, but the users sliding is extremely visually bad performance.

I want to block the slider from sliding past 70. So in pseudo-code its like this:

```
<Slider minimumValue={0} maximumValue={100} maxSlideValue={70} />
```

I know this `maxSlideValue` doesn't exist. But is there a way to do this? Even modifying the `Slider` implementation natively to achieve this?

### Further information

Here is my actual use case. Screenshot at bottom. We see I overlay sliders with position absolute over each other. I am trying to make a "range" slider where the start time cannot exceed the end time (and end time cannot precede the start time).

I have three things to solve in this screenshot here:

1. How to overlap that end slider, but allow interaction with start if press on start dot, and with end if end dot.
2. Make only the "union" of the dark red lines show. Because i want to express "in between".
3. The issue I asked about in this question, how to make start dot, not exceed end dot. And end dot not precede start dot.

[image]

Comment: @Halfer it means bad performance, you can see visual artifacts of where it should not be. Like when I set it to controlled at value 5, no matter if i slide it, it should not move. But with `<Slider>` it keeps moving and then coming back to 5. I edited it out of the OP.

Comment: Hey @Noitidart - did you find a solution for the "maxSlideValue"?

Comment: @RaideR I didn't :( I rolled some ugly custom solution.